# Couldn't able to prevent insert same data into Sqlite

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I have application in which I need one data entry only once. I did search for solution and applied it, but still same data record inserting again.

My code as follows:

In SqliteHelper class(Insert method):

```
    public boolean insertData(ContactModel contactModel) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(col_0,contactModel.getId());
        contentValues.put(col_1,contactModel.getName());
        contentValues.put(col_2,contactModel.getNumber());
        contentValues.put(col_3,contactModel.getColor());
        contentValues.put(col_4,contactModel.getFSize());
//        long result =db.insert(Table_name,null,contentValues);

        long result = db.insertWithOnConflict(Table_name, null, contentValues,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

method in activity for inserting data:

```
public void DataAdd(String name,String num,int color,int size){
    boolean indata = myhelper.insertData(new ContactModel(name,num,color,size));

    if (indata == true) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DataSave",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"In Data not True",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Crating table:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ Table_name +"(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, NUMBER TEXT, COLOR INTEGER, FSIZE INTEGER) ");

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use Primary key for that table?

Comment: i am using it , You can see in now , i edit post

Comment: uninstall app and re-install app and try again

Comment: @vasudev still the same, if u have any other way for achieving same result inform me

Comment: remove this  contentValues.put(col_0,contactModel.getId()); uninstall app and run app

Comment: @vasudev still same result . what i m going to do now is storing one of filed into array while reading and apply condition when inserting data

Comment: refer this example may be it helpful for you : https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-sqlite-database-example/

Answer (score 0):

when definition table must use primary key for id :

```
  private static final String DB_CREATE_MY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
        "  id        INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY ," +
        "  xofId     INTEGER  NULL," +
        "  code      INTEGER  NULL" +
        ");";
```

if you want increase id automatic use :

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT,
```

Comment: in your activity use query `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE NAME = name and ....` if result is zero , insertData()  .

Comment: and if you use AUTOINCREMENT for id must remove `contentValues.put(col_0,contactModel.getId());`